# How to make loop in Pascal

Tags: pascal

I just started learning Pascal and have issue.
Need to create a program that outputs the following result:

```
Input real number and press enter!: 4
****
***
**
*
```

I've come this far, but not figure out what to do next.

```
program project1;
var
  i, x:byte;
  y:char;
begin
  write('Ievadiet veselu skaitli: ');
  readln(x);
  y:='*';
  for i:=x downto 1 do writeln(y:3);
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: if input '7' output 7 lines with '*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two loops do have to be involved, but breaking out that inner loop functionality into a separate procedure can make it much easier to understand what's going on.

We can also declare `y` as `const`.

```
program project1;
const
  y = '*';

var
  i, x : byte;
 
  procedure writeln_n_times(x : char; n : byte);
  var
    i : byte;
  begin
    for i := 1 to n do
      write(x);
    writeln();
  end;

begin
  write('Ievadiet veselu skaitli: ');
  readln(x);

  for i := x downto 1 do
    writeln_n_times(y, i);
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

use two loops:

```
program project1;
var
  i, j,x:byte;
  y:char;
begin
  write('Ievadiet veselu skaitli: ');
  readln(x);
  y:='*';
  for i:=x downto 1 do 
  begin
    for j:=i-1 downto 1 do 
    begin
        write(y);
        end;
        
   writeln();
    end;  
end.
```

output:

```
Ievadiet veselu skaitli: 7
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```